# mp3 header reading problem in android

Tags: java, android

hi
i am doing a program for reading mp3 header. i get reading source code from the [site](http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/samples.html).
if aware of this site or mp3 header reading. please help me.

code is:

```
    File oSourceFile = new File("D:\\Mp3\\a.mp3");

    // create an MP3File object representing our chosen file
    MediaFile oMediaFile = new MP3File(oSourceFile);

    // any tags read from the file are returned, in an array, in an order which you should not assume
    ID3Tag[] aoID3Tag = oMediaFile.getTags();
    // let's loop through and see what we've got
    // (NOTE:  we could also use getID3V1Tag() or getID3V2Tag() methods, if we specifically want one or the other)
    for (int i=0; i < aoID3Tag.length; i++)
    {
        // check to see if we read a v1.0 tag, or a v2.3.0 tag (just for example..)
        if (aoID3Tag[i] instanceof ID3V1_0Tag)
        {
            ID3V1_0Tag oID3V1_0Tag = (ID3V1_0Tag)aoID3Tag[i];
            // does this tag happen to contain a title?
            if (oID3V1_0Tag.getTitle() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Title = " + oID3V1_0Tag.getTitle());
            }
            // etc.
        }
        else if (aoID3Tag[i] instanceof ID3V2_3_0Tag)
        {
            ID3V2_3_0Tag oID3V2_3_0Tag = (ID3V2_3_0Tag)aoID3Tag[i];
            // check if this v2.3.0 frame contains a title, using the actual frame name
            if (oID3V2_3_0Tag.getTIT2TextInformationFrame() != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Title = " + oID3V2_3_0Tag.getTIT2TextInformationFrame().getTitle());
            }
            // but check using the convenience method if it has a year set (either way works)
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Year = " + oID3V2_3_0Tag.getYear());  // reads TYER frame
            }
            catch (ID3Exception e)
            {
                // error getting year.. if one wasn't set
                System.out.println("Could get read year from tag: " + e.toString());
            }
            // etc.
        }
    }
```

run the code i get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

my console output:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/framework/TestCase
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.blinkenlights.jid3.test.ID3Test.testWriteV1_0Tag(ID3Test.java:60)
at org.blinkenlights.jid3.test.ID3Test.main(ID3Test.java:46)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.framework.TestCase
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     --- testWriteV1_0Tag ---

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `testWriteV1_0Tag` depends on [JUnit](http://junit.org/), which isn't in your classpath. Either change your code so it's *not* using JUnit (and not depending on anything else which uses JUnit) or include JUnit in your path.

Comment: i include JID3-0.46.jar in my path. i do not understand JUnit. please assist me.

Comment: @murali_ma: Unless you really *want* to use JUnit, you should take out the code that uses it rather than adding it to your classpath. Otherwise, you should download the JUnit package (see the link in my answer) and include it in your classpath in a way which will depend on how you're running this. For example, from the command line you'd use --classpath.

Comment: sorry for delay, i come back now.
i download the JUnit jar from you have mentioned site. i added the jar to build path. still i get error. i am using eclipse. please help me.

Comment: @murali_ma: I suspect you haven't added it in the right way then - it's hard to say for sure. But you really need to work out what you're trying to do - if you don't want to be running unit tests, you shouldn't need JUnit.

Comment: sorry for delay, i come back to the task now. i include following JUnit jars junit-4.9b2.jar and build path->add build path. but i get the same error. i do not know what is the problem. please assist me.

Comment: @murali_ma: It may be that you need JUnit 3.8.1 (a pretty common alternative before JUnit 4). But as I've said several times, consider removing the need for JUnit instead, unless you really want to run these as unit tests...

Comment: i am struggling with remove that JUnit part and find out the part. so that i am including jars. i do not know which parts is related to JUnit. please help me.

Comment: @murali: I've already told you the next thing to try: JUnit 3.8.1.

Comment: i try that JUnit 3.8.1 jar also. it throws class not found exception.
c:\work\jid3\test_data\notags.mp3 (The system cannot find the path specified). but in my coding any where i include this line.
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.blinkenlights.jid3.test.ID3Test.copy(ID3Test.java:158)
 at org.blinkenlights.jid3.test.ID3Test.testWriteV1_0Tag(ID3Test.java:60)
 at org.blinkenlights.jid3.test.ID3Test.main(ID3Test.java:46)

--- testWriteV1_0Tag ---
this is the out put. please

Comment: @murali_ma: Are you sure that's really a **class** not found exception rather than a **file** not found exception? I suspect the code in `testWriteV1_0Tag` specifies that file.

Comment: sorry it is file not found exception. i have not included any other class.

Comment: @murali_ma: I'm afraid you're going to have to take it from here on your own. I can't hand-hold you all through working out what's executing what, what files they need etc. We'd be here for hours. If you're still having problems, it would almost certainly be faster to find someone physically close by who's a little more confident in Java and Eclipse, and ask them to have a look with you.